# Getting result before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the result of a form before the submit? I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <form name="form">
                <input type="text" />
                <br />
                <input type="text" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <p class="congrats"></p>
        <input style="width:100px" value="check" id="a" type="button" />
        <script>
            //Get amount of empty inputs
            $("#a").onload('click', function () {
                var bad = 0;
                $('.form :text').each(function () {
                    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "")
                        bad++;
                });
                if (bad > 0)
                    $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing');
                else
                    $('.congrats').hide();
                //Get total inputs
                console.log("Total inputs " + form.getElementsByTagName('input').length);
                //Divide by complete inputs out of 100%
                console.log("The percentage is " + 100 / form.getElementsByTagName('input').length + "%");
                //Minus total inputs
                console.log(form.getElementsByTagName('input').length - bad);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But how can I get the result before the actual click, rather pageload? Onload?

Comment: unless you are loading up values from a database into the form, they will all be "" on load or ready. you probably want to handle it in the click, but prevent the default behavior if you find your bad results.

Comment: what is #a? Give us more information

Comment: Its the form. Look at the edit @martynas

Comment: @user302975 OK, that made things more clear. You want to prevent the default behaviour of the button. Look at my answer.

Comment: Can you explain why you're checking for empty fields on load? Like I said originally, unless you're pre-populating the fields from a database, they will always be empty...and therefore "bad."

Comment: Its for a progress thing. I get the amount of fields, Divide it, getting a percent, then setting that as the progress bar location @ethorn10

Comment: @user302975 to make your last jsbin work, you'll need to actually call the `countMissing` function. Check [this update of your jsbin](http://jsbin.com/notitimu/4/edit)

Comment: Works nice. Post an answer? @ethorn10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the code you provided in your updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/notitimu/1/edit), you'll just need to explicitly call your `countMissing()` function:

```
countMissing();

//Get amount of empty inputs
function countMissing() {
    var bad = 0;
    $('.form :text').each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") bad++;


    });

    if (bad > 0) $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing');
    else $('.congrats').hide();
    //Get total inputs
    console.log("Total inputs "+form.getElementsByTagName('input').length);
    //Divide by complete inputs out of 100%

    console.log("The percentage is " + 100/form.getElementsByTagName('input').length+"%");


    //Minus total inputs
    console.log(form.getElementsByTagName('input').length - bad);
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/notitimu/4/edit)**

Comment: This works nicely, but now when I submit, how would I get the amount of inputs completed? Or would this be another post?

Comment: Yes. Ask that in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.onload` instead of `.on()`: http://jsfiddle.net/2Bt88/1/

You also need to prevent the default behaviour of the button, and then continue:

```
$("#a").on("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do stuff

    // Submit the form
    e.submit();
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Bt88/)**

Comment: if(bad===0) e.submit(); otherwise it's exactly what I wanted to write :)

Comment: Hmm this isn't working for some reason. I don't get the message in the console before I submit....

Comment: Hang on, i'll do a jsfiddle

Comment: @user302975 you made no mention of a console message in your post. you should consider adding more code.

Comment: I don't understand how that works. I want to know the number of input fields before the user presses submit....

Comment: You are using `.onload` instead of `.on()` @user302975 http://jsfiddle.net/2Bt88/1/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/bukucone/1/edit Open the console and press check in the result. You'll see `50%` somewhere. I want to get that result when the page loads, not when the user submits

Comment: The have a function that deals with the calculation. Call it when page is loaded.

Comment: Yes like that, but I can't seem to get it working with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code

```
if (form.getElementsByTagName('input').length - bad === 0) 
        return false;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tze9M/